Unable to install ISO of 22.04 server from usb to box using text cli in place of gui
I am trying to install the 22.04 Ubuntu server on a Valencia AH-H box.
I can console in via serial in Putty.
Fedora is currently installed and will let me boot.
I cannot get it to install Ubuntu from the USB ISO that I created using Rufus as admin on my Windows machine.



Other versions of Grub are the standard, setting tty to ttyS0 and adding commands in front of the CD file boot.
This will not load past the boot page regardless of install options.
Any advice would be appreciated.

An alternative might be to extract and clone from a compressed image of an [already installed] Ubuntu Server. See this link. Read the whole thread before deciding to use that method.
